# Calling C# DLL from ASP on Compact Framework (Windows CE)

Tags: asp-classic, compact-framework, windows-ce, com-interop

I am writing an ASP application on Windows CE that will need to call business logic that exists in a .NET DLL (C#).

It appears as though although the Compact Framework allows us to call native code from managed code, the CF doesn't allow us to call managed code from native code. - But, I'm not 100% sure on this.

Has anyone had success using COM Interop to call methods from a managed dll from ASP on CF? If so, can you point me to where I can learn how to do it?

If not, given that I must use ASP (on CF) and I'm stuck with the business logic in a managed assembly, how else can I get data out of the assembly into the ASP application?

Comment: this may help- http://weblogs.asp.net/dneimke/archive/2004/01/31/65330.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just notified of a blog post by John Spaith (WinCE Team Member) -

> ...the Compact Framework does not
>   allow you to call managed code from
>   native, so you can't have your
>   ISAPI/ASP page call out into managed. 
>   (You can do managed code->native
>   calls, but not the other way around.)

[Here's the link to Spaith's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cenet/archive/2004/11/18/265864.aspx)

Comment: Correct, the default web server cannot call your managed component.  It also has a whole lot of other things that meake it a major challenge to write for (the lack of ability to debug pages being a big one)