# Calling Unmanaged DLL from classic asp in Windows CE

Tags: asp-classic, windows-ce, unmanaged

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071496/calling-c-sharp-dll-from-asp-on-compact-framework-windows-ce) stating that managed DLLs cannot be called from classic ASP code in Windows CE, but what about unmanaged?

More specifically, this [page](http://www.tizag.com/aspTutorial/aspDLL.php) explains how to call a DLL from ASP, but the first step is to register the DLL, and I couldn't find a way of doing this in CE.

Is it possible to call an unmanaged dll from classic asp in Windows CE? If so, how can I register and call it?

[Edit] By the way, I'm using Windows CE 2013

Comment: Think this might help with the registering bit [Registering DLL on windows mobile 6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20304380/692942). Think `regsvrce.exe` is included with the Windows Mobile SDKs.

Comment: It will depend on whether the unmanaged DLL exposes COM+, if it does once it registered you should be able to call it using `Set obj = Server.CreateObject("classname or class guid")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a "plain" DLL. A DLL that is just exporting some functions. This means that you can't, for example, call any Windows CE API inside your ASP page.
However you can create COM objects (using the Server.CreateObject statement) and those object must be implemented in native code and so they can access all the OS APIs. You can use ATL to simplify development of COM objects (I said simplify, not make it simple!). 
There is no way to invoke objects implemented using .NET since the .NET CF runtime can't be loaded inside a native exe and the HTTP server is running in the contest of a native EXE.

Comment: And don't forget to implement `IObjectSafety` in your COM object, or you'll end up pulling your hair out wondering why the browser can't create it.

Comment: In this case you are creating it from ASP code on the server. I suppose that the interface is needed when you develop a control that is going to be loaded inside the browser.